# Generate thumbnail of powerpoint documents

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

Is there a way to generate a thumbnail (jpg) of a powerpoint (ppt or pptx) document using an automated script? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using Windows Shell programming.

> The Windows Shell provides a native COM interface for accessing a file's preview image 
>   called IExtractImage

This article is offered in the context of Sharepoint, but it outlines how any program can extract a preview image:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289172.aspx

There is also an approach using Office Web Apps

http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2011/05/document-thumbnails-and-powerpoint.html